# How to properly render html conditionally based on screen size in conjunction with ssr in vue/nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server-side-rendering

Let's say i have markup to be rendered only for desktop via v-if.

If it's mobile it should render something v-else.

I am using the package vue-mq which allows for setting a default breakpoint which should be used for server side rendering.

When i put 'sm' in there and load the page from a desktop the browser obviously first receives the 'sm' version of the site which might differ from the 'lg' version.

Therefore a mismatch is caused showing up in the console.

What's the right way of conditionally rendering html content for ssr in nuxt/vuejs?

Any ideas on how to properly solve this without having the user load both versions of markup (like when using v-show instead of v-if which solves the mismatch but does add to the bandwidth usage)?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [@nuxtjs/device](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/device). When a http request hits your Nuxt app, this module inspects the user agent header and determines if the user agent (that is, the device the request originated from) is a mobile, a tablet, a desktop etc. This happens server side, before your client side code executes, and so v-if’s in templates will be handled properly.

For example:

`v-if="$device.isMobile"`

Comment: Thank you! Great module! Didn't know about that one.
One thing that is kind of a bummer though is, that it does not take screen sizes into account to match the media queries set through bootstrap / vue-mq.

So what might happen is that some parts are not shown for tablet (because bootstrap class .d-md-none for example) and some are shown (v-if="$isTablet") when its a tablet of 1440px.

Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: That's a great point. Unfortunately, there is no work around and you need to build out your app with this in mind. I know vue-mq claims to "support" SSR, but what that really means is it allows you to set a default breakpoint value (eg. ```defaultBreakpoint: 'sm'```) for use on the server-side. The client-side will update this once javascript kicks in and has access to the ```window``` to grab the actual viewport dimensions. You simply cannot detect viewport dimensions on the server-side at this point!

Comment: I just re-read your question and realised you were probably already aware of what I mentioned in my comment. Sorry if it wasn't helpful! The only thing I can think to mention, is maybe consider *bandwidth* the more important metric to consider when dealing with conditional rendering. If someone is viewing your app on a tablet/desktop, it might be acceptable to assume they're on WiFi and the extra mark-up is no big deal. If they're on mobile (which ```$device.isMobile``` can detect), assume they're more likely to be on 3G/4G and render/hide bandwidth-intensive content accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. After tinkering around the error is just gone without having changed anything (i believe at least). Weird stuff...